# How to Provide support for the browsers who don't support HTML 5?

Tags: html, browser

I want to create a webPage using HTML 5 which will use all the attractive features of HTML5 i.e. audio, video, autofocus, placeholder, required, email, url, number etc. and the webPage should also have support for the browsers which dont support HTML5 like IE or some versions of other popular browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, opera etc.

How do I start working on that, as You might guess that this is just for the experimental purpose and I am supposed to it asap... so please suggest me any help, site or blog or tutorial or example.. I have seen hhtml5Doctor.com and diveintohtml5.ep.io ... the sites are of great help...

Comment: why this -1 ? I asked which I need.. provided the work I have done so far ? didn't use any offensive language ? than y this -1 ?

Comment: You already have one of the best resources you can get on accomplishing this: diveintohtml.com. In fact, I would recommend reading the book itself has it has tons of great examples and instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use progressive enhancement.  The diveintohtml5 already tells you how: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html

Answer (score 1):

[html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) is a good start, it includes [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)/[html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) for barebones support of the new elements.

Other things may need javascript/flash fallbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that browsers will ignore tag that they don't understand.  So, for example, you can have an `audio` tag and inside that put an `object` tag for a flash audio player.  The HTML5 browser will understand the `audio` tag and do the right thing, and ignore the child content.  An older browser will see the `audio` tag and throw it away beacuse it doesn't understand it, but will render the child contents of the tag instead (the flash player).

Answer (score 0):

[swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) are really nice tools... u must give them a try... I would personally recommend swfObject due to very good support.